# Лямбда выражения и функторы в стандартных алгоритмах

Tags: c++, алгоритм, лямбда-выражение

Опишите пожалуйста плюси и минусы  вариантов  для конкретно этого примера(применение в std::for_each) , и когда и почему лямбда имеет преимущество(или наоборот)  по отношению к функтору:

```
 ...
void f(const int value)
{
    cout << value << endl;
}

int main()
{    
    vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    function<void(int)> op(&f) ; // функтор
    auto p = [](const int i) { return f(i + 5); }; // лямбда
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), op); // первый вариант
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), p);   // второй вариант
    ...
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, лямбда всего лишь более удобная запись функтора, так что разницы нет.

Comment: @freim Действительно, разницы между лямбдой и простым функтором (т.е. классом с перегруженным `operator()`) быть не должно. А вот `std::function`, у которого под капотом type erasure, по идее должен работать медленее...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  я тоже так думаю, но еще и  for_each возвращает применяемую операцию, которая может хранить в себе нужные данные для дальнейшего использования(хотя в этом примере нет ничего подобного). Вот почему  я приоритетно задал вопрос с этим альгоритмом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве вишенки :)

Создаю вектор и иже с ним:

```
void f(int value)
{
     sum += value;
}
const int Count = 100000000;
vector<int> v(Count);
generate(v.begin(),v.end(),g);
function<void(int)> op(&f);
```

Затем просто суммирую в глобальную переменную:

```
for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),f);
for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const int i) { sum += i; });
for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),op);
```

VC++2017 дал на моей машине следующие времена (в мс) - 187, 41 и 208 соответственно.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/fzPzWe) дает примерно те же результаты.

P.S. Явное создание

```
struct Sum
{
    void operator()(int value)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
};
```

как и следовало ожидать, от лямбды ничем не отличается.

Answer (score 6):

Ну, во-первых, в такой ситуации вы можете передавать в алгоритм прямо сразу `f`. Никакой оболочки вокруг `f` из лямбды или из `std::function` тут формально не требуется. (Разумеется, если вы хотите прибавить `5` к аргументу, то лямбда - именно то, что надо.)

Во-вторых, при создании, удалении и на каждом вызове `std::function` тянет за собой накладные расходы, связанные с затратами на *type erasure* внутри `std::function`. Поэтому передавать `std::function` лучше только туда, где на входе требуется именно `std::function`. `std::function` предназначен в первую очередь для устранения зависимости принимающего алгоритма от шаблонного параметра, описывающего тип функтора.

В вашем случае, т.е. для `std::for_each`, никакой речи о таком устранении не идет: в `std::for_each` тип функтора уже присутствует в списке шаблонных параметров, никто его не устранял и устранять не собирается. И поэтому платить накладные расходы за `std::function` нет никакого смысла. Лямбда тут будет работать эффективнее.

Это относится ко всем стандартным алгоритмам: у них у всех типы функторов, предикатов, компараторов и т.п. вынесены в список параметров шаблона. В такой ситуации нет смысла использовать `std::function` без каких-то дополнительных/посторонних на то причин.

Comment: Нет вопросов после такого ответа